# Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=3.9.1.0. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating the object for class ApplicationBrowser which is present in one solution where I am passing one path as a string and it creates an instance of chrome driver. Chromedriver is the API present in the . When I do this I'm experiencing the following exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=3.9.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. 
A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
```

My Code:

```
ApplicationBrowser webApp = new ApplicationBrowser(path);


public ApplicationBrowser(string driverLocation)
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            Wb = new ChromeDriver(driverLocation, options);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not declaring a WebDriver:

```
WebDriver wb = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Missing the WebDriver in front of wb

Also, make sure you have the right WebDriver:
https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: I have the WebDriver as the seperate internal propery which is Iwebdriver. I can't debug this code because it is not hitting into this class. I suspect this to be chrome driver version mismatch issue i don't know how to ressolve. If anyone face the same issue. Please let me know the solution.